# Error in v-on handler (Promise/async): "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'dispatch')"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Tengo el error:

> Error in v-on handler (Promise/async): "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'dispatch')"
> cuando intento hacer el login comunicandome a una accion en vuex por medio de dispatch.

Así tengo el archivo principal de Vue (main.js):

**`main.js`**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import DashboardPlugin from './plugins/dashboard-plugin';
import App from './App.vue';

// router setup
import router from './routes/router';
import store from './store';
// plugin setup
Vue.use(DashboardPlugin);

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  store,
  router,
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App),
});
```

El archivo que llama store es el siguiente:
**`index.js`**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import axios from 'axios' 
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

Vue.use(Vuex);
 
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {},
    mutations: {},
    actions: {
        async login(raw){
            await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/sanctum/csrf-cookie')
            await axios.post('http://localhost:8000/login',raw)
        }, 
      
    },
    modules: {}

})

export default store
```

Y el método de vue donde llamo a la acción login es este:

**`login.vue`**

```
  methods: {
  onSubmit() {
    this.$store.dispatch('login');

    }
 }
```

Si desde el main.js yo llamo al dispatch `store.dispatch('login') si me esta funcionando pero desde el login me devuelve el error de la pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solucion del error fue el siguiente codigo

```
Vue.prototype.$store = store
```

con esa linea de codigo la variable store quedo de manera global.
ESspero que a alguien mas le pueda servir.